# How to get counts in Mysql Left Join?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

I have  tables department and employee.
Schema  is like ,

```
department(id, name)
employee(id,depid,salary)
```

i need to get the count of employees in each department.
My query in mysql is like

```
select d.depname,count(e.id) 
from employe as e left join department as d on d.depid 
where e.depid=d.depid group by d.depid;
```

but the result set contain only the department with employees in it.
I needed those departments with 0 employees as zero itself.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63551/5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just interchange the table names,

```
SELECT  d.name, 
        COUNT(e.id) totalEmployeeCount
FROM    department AS d 
        LEFT JOIN employee AS e 
            ON e.depid = d.id
GROUP   BY d.id;
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 1):

```
select d.depname,count(e.id) from employee as e 
right join department as d on d.depid = e.depid 
group by d.depid;
```

For the reason, go through http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html